# Textbox CSS hover

Tags: css, textbox, popup, hover

I have a textbox in xul firefox application and I generate some text from this textbox and paste it in my website.

How do I show a popup message or some message when someone puts the cursor on the generated text?

My browser is Firefox.

Thanking you guys in Advance.

karthik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this with Javascript: `<span onmouseover="alert('Message');">Generated text here.</span>`

Comment: The `onmouseover` property is something that is executed when the user puts the cursor over the element. `alert('Message');` is a javascript pop-up that displays `Message`. The `span` HTML tag is used to apply the property to the text. It could be done differently, but I don't have your code so that was my suggestion.

Comment: Hi Here is my code : <box orient="horizontal">
     <textbox id="tb" multiline="true"  flex="2" rows="7" cols="242" value = ""
         clickSelectsAll="true" spellcheck="true" hidespinbuttons="true" wraparound="off" select="true" >
     </textbox>   
</box>     I will make a copy of generated text from this textbox and paste it on my website.

Comment: When is the pop-up supposed to happen? When the cursor is over the text box or over the text in your web page?